# Generate log for last modified date of all files in a folder using CMD?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, directory

I have a folder of about 130 files, and I want to use a CMD prompt to generate a single .txt file with all their names and last modified dates. I've looked into DIR and .LastWriteTime but I can't figure it out. All I've searched about this topic leads to using Powershell or Batch or Linux but I don't have any of these resources, only CMD. I'm new to using CMD, but the worst part is that I got this done about a month ago and I cannot remember how I got this done! Incredibly frustrating.

Thank you so much!

EDIT: In the off chance it helps, last time I used such command (which I forgot about, and for the life of me I seem not to be able to find again), it generated this following file, maybe this may serve as a visual cue of what's the command I'm talking about. Once again thanks!

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----         2/10/2018   3:55 PM      162256779 mobizen_20180210_155420.mp4
-a----         2/10/2018   4:18 PM      111595959 mobizen_20180210_161816.mp4
-a----         2/10/2018   4:20 PM       32643884 mobizen_20180210_162027.mp4
-a----         7/15/2018   6:15 PM       60733357 mobizen_20180715_181514.mp4
-a----          8/5/2018   5:08 PM      126381736 mobizen_20180805_170721.mp4
-a----         8/30/2018   4:53 PM       81903211 mobizen_20180830_165306.mp4
```

Comment: The command output shown in your question is from PowerShell, example `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\cangrejo\Music' -Filter *.mp4 -File`. However that is providing more information than you need, so you may wish to `select` only the parts you require, e.g. `Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\cangrejo\Music' -Filter *.mp4 -File | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime, Name`. If you wanted to do that in cmd instead then perhaps this is what you wanted, `For %G In ("C:\Users\cangrejo\Music\*.mp4") Do @Echo %~ntxG`. I'll leave it to you to add the required command to output each to a `.txt` file.

Comment: That output is from a PowerShell command: `Get-ChildItem -Path 'X:\somefolder' | Format-Table -AutoSize`

Comment: Or you could even go a little bit off-grid with this in PowerShell, `Get-CimInstance -Query "Select * From Cim_DataFile Where Drive='C:' And Path='\\Users\\cangrejo\\Music\\' And Extension='mp4'" | Select-Object -Property @{Label = 'Name'; Expression = {Split-Path $_.Name -Leaf}}, @{Label = 'LastWriteTime'; Expression = {$_.LastModified}}`.

Comment: You could also perform the task in cmd.exe using the `ForFiles` utility, with the added feature of your output strings being double-quoted, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\forfiles.exe /P "C:\Users\cangrejo\Music" /M *.mp4 /C "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /D /C \"If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @FDate @File\""`.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `powershell.exe`, the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) from your batch file - such a call is costly in terms of performance, but gives you access to PowerShell's superior capabilities:

In the simplest case:

```
@echo off

:: Add / remove property names in the Select-Object call as needed.
:: If the dir. path has embedded spaces, enclose it in '...' or \"...\"
powershell.exe -noprofile -c ^
  "Get-ChildItem C:\Users\cangrejo\Music\*.mp4 | Select-Object Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name" ^
  > out.txt
```

<sup>Note: The above selection of output columns (properties) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) happens to be the *default* set of columns shown in [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem)'s formatted output. If this default set will do, you can omit the `Select-Object` call; otherwise, modify the list of property names to suit your needs.</sup>

Note that the resulting file contains output that is formatted for the *human observer*, not for *programmatic processing*.
(And if you want more control over this for-display formatting, you can pipe your data to one of PowerShell's `Format-*` cmdlets, such as [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table).)

If you need later programmatic processing, use a structured text format such as CSV, via PowerShell's [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) cmdlet:

```
@echo off

powershell.exe -noprofile -c ^
  "Get-ChildItem C:\Users\cangrejo\Music\*.mp4 | Select-Object Mode, LastWriteTime, Length, Name | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation out.csv"
```

Either way, you could easily add *sorting* by piping to
[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object) `LastWriteTime -Descending` before output, for instance.

*Character-encoding* note:

- In the first command it is `cmd.exe` that saves to a file, using the encoding of the active code page, as reflected in the output from `chcp`; the default is the active *OEM* code page.
- In the second command it is the default encoding of PowerShell's `Export-Csv` cmdlet that is used, which in Windows PowerShell defaults to ASCII(!) (in PowerShell (Core) 7+ it is now fortunately (BOM-less) UTF-8); use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify a different encoding; you can apply the same technique to the first command by appending  `| Out-File -Encoding ...` to the PowerShell command instead of letting `cmd.exe` save the file.

Answer (score 1):

As the question is specific to using [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd), and not a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), or [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)…

> All I've searched about this topic leads to using Powershell or Batch
> or Linux but I don't have any of these resources, only CMD.

…you should not have included those tags.

Also as you've specifically stated that you…

> want to use a CMD prompt to generate a single .txt file with all
> their names and last modified dates.

…not the file attributes, file sizes, or table-like labelled headers; what follows is a modification of the example code in my opening comment. This time ensuring that **all** files are included, as per your question, *(a standard `for` loop enumerates non hidden files)*, and including the redirection of the results to a `.txt` file too.

The below example has used relative paths for the target directory, *(`.\Music`)*, and output file, *(`.\Desktop`)*, so you may wish to change those to suit your actual situation. Also noting that the PowerShell output you've posted in your question body has outputted its results ordered alphabetically by filename, I have ensured that this does the same.

```sh
Dir ".\Music" /B /A:-D 1>NUL 2>&1 && (For /F "Delims= EOL= " %G In ('Dir ".\Music" /B /A:-D /O:N 2^>NUL') Do @For %H In (".\Music\%G") Do @Echo %~ntxH) 1> ".\Desktop\list.txt"
```

---

As a side note, if you wish to also have the attributes and filesizes, as in your PowerShell output, a simple change could achieve that too:

```sh
Dir ".\Music" /B /A:-D 1>NUL 2>&1 && (For /F "Delims= EOL= " %G In ('Dir ".\Music" /B /A:-D /O:N 2^>NUL') Do @For %H In (".\Music\%G") Do @Echo %~antxzH) 1> ".\Desktop\list.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

For any directory your result will be returned by the default command, it just needs to be filtered by extension. Note this is not the best way for fast processing in a correct fashion **see the better PowerShell solution already given by @mklement0**

```
PowerShell Get-ItemProperty -Path *.mp4
```

then to save to file list you add `> MP4.log`

If the files are in another directory you use

```
PowerShell Get-ItemProperty -Path 'c:\some folder\with a space\*.mp4' > MP4.log
```

NOTE for PowerShell the 'single quotes' for a path with spaces.

Note:- if you dont need that first mode column you can do similar at the command line (For me CMD is faster than PowerShell) but you may need to edit for your local time output (Ignore my dummy data just a couple of old files I renamed) Note the list should default to time written but you could add /T:W if yours has any other over-ride.

**Likewise @Compo has answered with a better more comprehensive cmd solution.**

[image]

```
@echo Last Time written by me      Length Name>mp4.log & echo ---- ---- ------- -- --      ------ ---->>mp4.log & dir /A:-D /O:D |find ".mp4" >> mp4.log & type mp4.log
```

Comment: Just a note K J, to mention that the output from `DIR` is locale dependent, so the number of characters used may not match that in your output, and if the file sizes are larger, the number of characters in their output will change too. Those two together could potentially spoil the fixed width table-like output you were going for.

Comment: Just an aside: The PowerShell-idiomatic way to get the `System.IO.FileInfo` instances that result in the output shown in the question would be `Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\some folder\with a space\*.mp4'` or - when performance matters - with a `-Filter` argument, `Get-ItemProperty -LiteralPath 'c:\some folder\with a space' -Filter *.mp4`. In the context of the file system, the [`Get-ItemProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-itemproperty) is virtually never used - you can pass property names with `-Name`, but the formatted output is unhelpful.